# Here 'pointerdown' event on a map

Tags: jquery, maps

using an event like:

```
map.addEventListener('pointerdown', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.target);        
});
```

Gives me the output:

When clicking on an icon:
xi {pb: false, Ta: undefined, Ob: Dd, ph: xi, Me: P, …}

Clicking somewhere on the map:
Q {pb: false, Ta: Array(1), Ob: Dd, ph: Q, Me: null, …}

Where can I find a good description of the event with all the functions and how find out which one is on the map and which one is an the icon?

Regards
Chris

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerdown

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#the-pointerover-event#the-pointerover-event